# Feed not updating after clicking notification

Tags: bug, android-app

[image: Screenshot]

Hey, this is pretty much the first time I'm using the app.

I got a notification for a question I asked. It opened the app and the feed drawer, but it did not pull the actual notification. I was able to swipe down to refresh and then it showed up.